# Play Slick: How to fetch selected fields from a DB table in play-slick 3.0.0?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, slick-3.0, playframework-2.6, play-slick

I am new to play framework. I am working on a play slick based application where I want to fetch a list of objects from DB which will contains some selected fields. For fetching all the fields I am using following code:

```
case class Mail(txID: String,
               timeStamp: Long,
               toUserID: String,
               mailContent: String,
               mailTemplateFileName: String,
               fromID: String,
               toID: String
               )
```

```
def getLogFromIDFuture(userID: String): Future[Option[List[Mail]]] = cache.getOrElseUpdate[Option[List[Mail]]](userID) {
    val resultingUsers = db.run(mailsData.filter(x => x.toUserID === userID).result)
    val res = Await.result(resultingUsers, Duration.Inf)
    res.map(t => t) match {
      case t if t.nonEmpty =>
        Future(Some(t.toList))
      case _ => Future(None)
    }
  }
```

So my question is how to fetch only **timeStamp, toUserID, mailContent, fromID, toID** fields as the list of objects like `UserMessage(timeStamp: Long, toUserID: String, mailContent: String, fromID: String, toID: String)`. I tried searching about this but didn't get any convincing answers.

Comment: So instead of returning all the mailsData you just map it with the things you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in the comment you can do this:

```
def getLogFromIDFuture(userID: String): Future[Option[List[UserMessage]]] = cache.getOrElseUpdate[Option[List[Mail]]](userID) {
    val resultingUsers = db.run(mailsData.filter(x => x.toUserID === userID).map(entry =>(entry.timeStamp, entry.toUserID, entry.mailContent, entry.fromID, entry.toID))
.result)// here you have the tuple of things
// add the mapping of the tuple to the UserMessage
    val res = Await.result(resultingUsers, Duration.Inf)
    res.map(t => t) match {
      case t if t.nonEmpty =>
        Future(Some(t.toList))
      case _ => Future(None)
    }
  }
```

You can get rid of that Await.result

```
    resultingUsers.map( match {
      case t if t.nonEmpty =>
       Some(t.toList)
      case _ => None
     }
)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am not able to figure out why it is complaining like "Required: Long, Found: Rep[Long]" near third line "UserMessage(entry.timeStamp" where actually timestamp is Long.

Comment: @ShashiShekhar hey, I edited, if you have more questions let me know

Comment: Sorry for late response. Thanks for the help and sure I will let you know for more questions.